# Modifying single json value in Riak through HTTP

Tags: json, curl, riak

I am learning to use the riak noSQL-database, but I have a question I have not found an answer to in several days.

I have a database entry like so:

```
{
   "Username" : "Pete",
   "Pets" : "Cat",
   "Car" : "Honda Civic",
   "Country" : "Canada"
}
```

I am updating the object like this:

```
curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:8098/buckets/users/keys/user01" -H "Content Type:application/json" 
-d '{"Username":"Peter"}'
```

As of now it replaces the entire object, but I would like to be able to update just the username field, without having to re-enter the entire object into my query.

I was trying to do a map using `-d '{"update":{"Username": "Peter"}}'` but it did not work out unfortunately.

Any thoughts if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are using Riak as a pure [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database). This means that the value is opaque and Riak knows nothing about its structure. The value of a key can only be replaced as a whole.

In order to be able to update individual fields of a document, you need to use a [document store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) and model your data accordingly. Another option is a column-oriented NoSQL database such as [Cassandra](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/what-is-apache-cassandra).

See also Riak website:

- [Key-Value Database Explained](http://basho.com/resources/key-value-databases/)
- [Implementing a Document Store](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/document-store/)